# Change access database path

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm in a bit over my head on this one. I work for a tax firm as a web developer. They have an old access database with all their info in it, and it's stuck on one rather old computer that's failing. I've made a php database with a web interface to replace it, but he's having trouble getting his workers to switch over to it.

So he's assigned me to find a way to move the database to a new computer.

I've never used access before, and despite my protests to my employer that it'd be easier just to hire someone online to do this for twenty bucks, the task falls to me.

I tell this story so that you'll forgive my lack of knowledge of the technical terms surrounding access.

What are the steps involved to move a database to another computer and let it know the new location of it's own data  (as well as let the remote client copies know where the data is located as well).

Comment: "I've made a php database"... hmmm, PHP is not a database management system... at most, it's a front-end to a database server

Comment: I've made a mySQL database with PHP as a front-end. I figured "PHP database" would be descriptive enough :P Though I guess PHP database would imply I was having PHP write it's data to text files or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic process is to move the database to a new shared folder. However, “often” for any multi-user Access application then the application is split into two parts.

The so called Front End (FE), and this is placed on each computer. This is the user interface part and continues the application code and forms/reports.

The so called Back End (BE), and this is placed in/on a shared folder on the server. This has ONLY the data tables - no code or forms (no UI parts).

Access has a built in splitter that will split a typical application into these two parts.

The FE and BE are regular mdb or since 2007 accDB files. If the location (UNC path name) of the back end is changed, then the FE needs to be re-linked to the new BE location. This is accomplished by using the linked table manager. As noted, if the application is NOT split, then simply moving the current application to a new shared folder will suffice and no code or change to the application need to occur.

So your first step is to determine if the database is split. It is strongly recommended that any Access application that is running as “file share” be split.

As a future longer term approach, you could move the back end data tables to MySQL or SQL server and CONTINUE to use the existing FE (the application part).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Access databases are stored in a single file (with extension `.accdb`), so you could only move that file to a new location.

However, you must make some precautions:

- Does the database is used as an ODBC data source? You'll have to change the DSN so it points to the new location
- Is it replicated? When you copy a replicated access database, you must make it the new main design
- Does the access file contains linked tables to other databases? You must be sure that those linked tables are accessible at the new location
- Is the access file the source of linked tables used in other files? You'll need to be sure that all those files point to the new location of the access file

Other than that, you must take the usual precautions: Backup everything relevant, check if the database works correctly in the new location, etcetera.

Personally, I recommend you migrate to a more robust platform (like MySQL or PostgreSQL) and migrate your data there

Comment: The reason the question was asked is because the users refuse to move to a new system and instead insist on using Access, which means a "more robust platform" is not possible. (It's stated in the question.)

Comment: If the access database is used via ODBC by the rest of the users, changing the DSN to a "more robust" platform would be transparent to them (just an example)

Comment: It's doubtful that any of the queries (or SQL) in an Access application would work unchanged, unless it's a very basic CRUD application. Very few Access desktop applications are DSN-based, in my experience.

Comment: Actually, I am not away of ANY sql quires in Access that fail to run when you move the back end data to MySQL or SQL server and use those SAME existing quires via the ODBC drive. So taking the data from Access and moving such data to SQL server means that 100% of the EXISTING quires and SQL used in that application will continue to run. I think the real issue is someone built a new application that uses don’t want to use and is blaming that fact on users want to use Access and gives no reason why the supposed new and improved application has not made users jump for joy and adopt the new system